# Why pyperclip.copy function works only when there is breakpoint in code?

Tags: python, pyperclip

If there is no break point - text not copied over to clipboard. If its present - it is. I am on fedora 37, debugging with vs code.

File and repo: https://github.com/kha-white/manga-ocr/blob/master/manga_ocr/ocr.py

Code:

```
def process_and_write_results(mocr, img_or_path, write_to):
    t0 = time.time()
    text = mocr(img_or_path)
    t1 = time.time()

    logger.info(f'Text recognized in {t1 - t0:0.03f} s: {text}')

    if write_to == 'clipboard':
        pyperclip.copy(text) # <--- here is the function
    else:
        write_to = Path(write_to)
        if write_to.suffix != '.txt':
            raise ValueError('write_to must be either "clipboard" or a path to a text file')

        with write_to.open('a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write(text + '\n')
```

Comment: You may want to try install xclip and xsel as advised by this [Github user](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/issues/61#issuecomment-415934948)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the fact that my system uses wayland, and paperclip uses xlip, which works "strangely" for wayland. After installing `wl-clipboard` and specifing it - coping works.

```
        pyperclip.set_clipboard("wl-clipboard")
        pyperclip.copy(text)
```